# touch through uiviews

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I've got a rootView. Now I add a subview to my rootView by using the method addSubView:. After that the subview is added consisting of a view containing several buttons. Now what I want is, to be able to press both, the buttons on my rootView and the buttons on my subView. However when I turn off user interaction of my subView, I can't press its buttons any more. However if I let it on, I cant press the buttons of my rootView.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your "subview," subclass UIView and override the the hitTest method like this:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UIView *subview = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
  if ( subview != self )
    return subview;
  else
    return nil;
}
```

This will cause the buttons and other views within your "subview" to respond to events, but the view itself will act as if it's not there.

Comment: Thanks! But now how do I implement this method onto my view in my xib file?

Comment: You need to create a new code file, make it a descendent of UIView, and implement that method.  Then go to your xib, select the view you want, and use the Identity pane to make it an instance of the UIView descendent class you just created.

Comment: Ah now I get it! Thanks a fortune Brian!!